# Incorporating shared "parameters" module into python program with multiple sub-modules?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a program `program.py` depending on a collection of modules (`module1.py`, `module2.py`, ...) that share a common parameters module (`parameters.py`).

Each of the modules imports `parameters.py` as `from parameters import *`.

What I would like to do is create many parameters modules representing different simulation conditions (`parameters1.py`, `parameters2.py`, ...) and fix which one gets imported to the modules (`module1.py`, `module2.py`, ...) by running `program.py` with a flag, as for example:

```
python program.py parameters33.py
```

This would run `program.py` by importing `parameters33.py` into all of its dependencies (`module1.py`, `module2.py`, ...).

Any advice or guidance as to how to implement this pattern would be appreciated. As of now my idea seems hacky making me think there is a better way.

For example, I want to run `python program.py parameters33.py` with `program.py` like:

```
import sys
params = sys.argv[1]
import module1 params
...
import modulen params
def do_stuff("modules and params"):
    return "something"
```

and (`modulen.py`):

```
import sys
params = sys.argv[1]
from params import *
def do_smaller_stuff("params"):
    return "something smaller"
```

Is this an appropriate structure? Or am I missing some functionality designed for this type of task dependent on a set of underlying parameters?

I have read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html and searched stackoverflow but haven't found much particularly bearing on this problem. Maybe I am searching wrong.

Comment: So you want to be able to dynamically import modules? https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: Seems like the right idea. Would you suggest a stucture like `parameters = importlib.import_module(sys.argv[1])`?

Comment: The function doesn't return anything. It only imports.

Comment: This will work. What is the `importlib.import_module("module")` equivalent of `from module import *`?

Comment: I'm sorry, the function does return something. So you can do `parameters = importlib.import_module(sys.argv[1]); from parameters import *`